# Testing controller with instance variables in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to test my #new view in a controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :current_cart
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private
    def current_cart
        @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id  
      @cart
    end 
end


class controller < ApplicationController
  def new
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, :notice => "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    @order = Order.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml { render :xml => @order }
    end  
  end
```

Spec:

```
  describe "GET #new" do
    it "renders the :new template" do
      product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
      @cart.add_product(product.id)
      get :new 
      response.should render_template :new
    end
  end
```

`@cart` is not defined??

Any clues, thank you

Comment: Why do you suppose `@cart` to be defined there?

Comment: You have to define `@cart` in your test.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check or add to @cart in the test.  You aren't testing the saving of the cart, you are testing whether or not your new would render.  If you took that out it would pass.  Also it's preferred not to rescue exceptions like that.  You can do a `@cart ||= Cart.find_or_create_by_id(session[:cart_id])` method instead

Edit:
I missed that redirect.

```
describe "GET #new" do    
  let(:cart)    { FactoryGirl.create(:cart) }
  let(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }

  it "renders the :new template" do
    cart.add_product(product.id)
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    get :new
    response.should render_template :new
  end
end
```

Comment: I understand that, but my controller logic in the new view is redirecting if the cart is empty.  How would I test the render then? Thanks

Comment: nice refactoring (removed the id to make it work) @cart ||= Cart.find_or_create_by(session[:cart_id])